# Values as an arraylist of Objects in HashMap

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap

I want to create a HashMap that stores key as an Integer value which is the ID of a restaurant. The value should be a List of the Restaurant objects. But my IDE is not happy with the way I am doing it while adding the restaurant object to the List. Here is my code:

```
public List getTopPerformers(List<RestaurantInfo> restaurants){

    HashMap <Integer, List<RestaurantInfo>> map = new HashMap<Integer,
                                             List< RestaurantInfo>>();
             // Key is restaurant ID. Value is the Object of Class RestaurantInfo
    List<RestaurantInfo> ll;
    for(RestaurantInfo restaurant: restaurants){

        map.put(restaurant.cityId, ll.add(restaurant));

    }
}
```

My Restaurant class has properties as cityId, orderCount and restaurantId.

The `map.put(restaurant.cityId, ll.add(restaurant));` line gives error as follows and obviously it will never compile.

```
no suitable method found for put(int,boolean)
method HashMap.put(Integer,List<RestaurantInfo>) is not applicable
```

### (actual argument boolean cannot be converted to List by method     invocation conversion)

Comment: I wouldn't expect `new List<RestaurantInfo>()` to compile, assuming it's `java.util.List`.

Comment: Editing the post and removing that.

Comment: Well now `ll` isn't initialized, so `ll.add` won't compile - use `new ArrayList<RestaurantInfo>()` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ll.add(restaurant) returns boolean.

So, when you do:

```
map.put(restaurant.cityId, ll.add(restaurant));
```

you are trying to add (int, boolean) to a map of type: (Integer,List)

Also, below code will add all restaurants to every cityid:

```
List<RestaurantInfo> ll = new List<RestaurantInfo>();
for(RestaurantInfo restaurant: restaurants){
    ll.add(restaurant);
    map.put(restaurant.cityId, ll);
}
```

I think what you need is:

```
List<RestaurantInfo> ll;
for (RestaurantInfo restaurant: restaurants) {
  // If restaurant is from the same city which is present in the map then add restaurant to the existing list, else create new list and add.
  if (map.containsKey(restaurant.cityId)) {
    ll = map.get(restaurant.cityId);
  } else {
    ll = new List<RestaurantInfo>();
  }
  ll.add(restaurant);
  map.put(restaurant.cityId, ll);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  map.put(restaurant.cityId, ll.add(restaurant));
```

In this statement,

```
ll.add(restaurant)
```

`return` value for add operation is `boolean`, which is why you are getting that error.

What you may need to do would be something like:

```
ll.add(restaurant);
map.put(restaurant.cityId, ll);
```

Comment: I got the error reason. And I tried the above changes. Don't you think this will simply add all the restaurant objects in the list. I want to have the key as the cityId and its corresponding value should be a list of restaurant objects only for that cityId. So essentially, every new cityId will have a new list attached to it as a value.

Comment: Then you  list declartion should be simple List<Integer, RestaurantInfo>./

Answer (score 1):

[**`add(E)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) function of a *collection* returns boolean: `true` If the data `E` is added and the *collection* structure has been changed  (Returns `false` if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element).

Hence:

```
for(RestaurantInfo restaurant: restaurants){
        map.put(restaurant.cityId, ll.add(restaurant));
    }
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
for(RestaurantInfo restaurant: restaurants){
            map.put(restaurant.cityId, boolean);
        }
```

So, First add the `resutaurant` instances to list `ll` one by one and then add `ll` list instance to the `map`.

**You might want to do something like this:**

```
RestaurantInfo restaurant =  resturants.get(0);
int cityId = restaurant.cityId;

List<RestaurantInfo> ll = new ArrayList<>();

for(RestaurantInfo restaurant: restaurants){
            ll.add(restaurant);
        }

 map.put(cityId, ll);
```